# asp.net - list/grid view customize layout

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, gridview

I am using asp.net vb...

I am trying from a couple of weeks to create custom list/grid view.

In VS2010 there are many controls but no one is allowing to creating custom view like this website...

http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/html-css-techniques/

**I want to customize something same like it with a picture thumbnail, a hyperlink, some text and a nice looking paging numbers. I try to find on google , youtube but no good example I got…
Please provide me steps to do it.**

JS

Comment: does Asp.Net Repeater not fit the requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asp.net ListView Control. 
It gives you full control over rendered html.

[Using ASP.NET 3.5's ListView and DataPager Controls](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122607-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the gridview to look like this, you will need to create only one visible column with no header showing and place all your controls into the content template of this column. From there you will have to manually style the controls to your required style.

If you have dynamic content in the rows, during rowdatabound of the gridview you can access each control using the findcontrol method and customize each control from there.